# I have an assignment to make a C program about maclaurin series, specifically the Sin X one. and i didn't know what im did wrong

Tags: c

[Maclaurin series Sinx][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0vnG.png

I actually already solve problem but using the pow(x,y). since my teacher haven't teach us using the pow function. So i tried using the "for loop" to increment the power

```
#include <stdio.h>
    
    int main() {
    
       
       int N;
       int factorial =1;
       int a=3;
       float sum;
       float x;
       int sign= 1;
    
       printf("enter N: ");
       scanf("%d", &N);
       
       printf("enter x in degrees: ");
       scanf("%f", &x);
       x=x/180*3.14;
       
       sum=x;
       printf("degrees in radian: %f ",x );
       
    
       for (a = 3; a <=N ; a+=2)
       {    
           int powersum= 1;
           for (int b=1; b<=a; b++)
            {
            powersum=powersum*(x);
            }
        
        factorial=factorial*a*(a-1);
        sum= sum + sign* powersum/ factorial;
        sign=sign*-1;
       }
       
        
        printf("\n sum: %.4f", sum);
    
        
        return 0;
    }
```

my output when i entered N= 10 and x= 45 is 0.7850 (should be 0.7071) and i dont know what i did wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- All of `sign`, `powersum`, and `factorial` are `int`, so *integer division* is done at `sign* powersum/ factorial` and the value becomes wrong. `powersum` should be `float`. If you want to support larger `n`, `factorial` should also be `float`.
- The initial value of `sign` is wrong. It should be `-1`, not `1` because the first thing to be added is `- x**3 / 3!`.
- Your value of pi is wrong and your program with the above two fix gave me the result `0.7068`. I got `0.7071` by using `3.1415` instead of `3.14`.